# Can a method really be binary compatible with a class-object (scala)?

Tags: scala, compatibility

The metrics-scala project got a [pull-request](https://github.com/erikvanoosten/metrics-scala/pull/365) that suggests to change:

```scala
class Meter {
  def exceptionMarker: new AnyRef() {
    def apply[A](f: => A): A = ???
  }
}
```

to the much nicer:

```scala
class Meter {
  object exceptionMarker {    // only this line changed
    def apply[A](f: => A): A = ???
  }
}
```

However, I am afraid this causes binary incompatibility. Of course I checked with  [Mima](https://github.com/lightbend/mima). Mima does not complain.

So my question is: is Mima right, and is the proposed change really binary compatible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact you can even implement/override a `def` with an `object` in a subclass.

```
trait Foo
trait A {
  def foo: Foo
}
class B extends A {
  object foo extends Foo
}
```

So yes, I am fairly sure it should be backwards binary compatible.

Comment: spec says that `object` member is just a `lazy val`, so I agree.

Comment: Nice! After 9 years of Scala I am still learning something new 